# Flask object has no attribute get while following linode tutorial

Tags: python, flask

Good morning,

Following the linode tutorial here to create a RESTful API
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/create-restful-api-using-python-and-flask/

I keep getting an attribute error *'Flask' object has no attribute 'get'*

Not sure what's going on because I'm following the tutorial precisely.

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

in_memory_datastore = {
   "COBOL" : {"name": "COBOL", "publication_year": 1960, "contribution": "record data"},
   "ALGOL" : {"name": "ALGOL", "publication_year": 1958, "contribution": "scoping and nested functions"},
   "APL" : {"name": "APL", "publication_year": 1962, "contribution": "array processing"},
}

@application.get('/programming_languages')
def list_programming_languages():
   return {"programming_languages":list(in_memory_datastore.values())}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running an older version of Flask (v2.0.x or below).

Flask added `@application.get` feature in v2.1.x branch (check [documentation here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)).

For older flask versions use `@application.route('/programming_languages', methods=['GET'])`. Documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#http-methods).